# Blazor - output HTML code inside IF statement, with ID tag

Tags: blazor

I am new to Blazor.  I have created a component where I pass an ID parameter.  I want this ID param to be added to a  tag IF a statement is true.  However, when I add the ID param to the HTML it actually renders the tags in double quotes

```
[Parameter] public string ID { get; set; }

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Tooltip))
{
@:"<span id=" + @ID + ">Show This</span>";
}
```

But it actually renders the above tag in double quotes

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code!

```
[Parameter] public string ID { get; set; }

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Tooltip))
 {
   <span id="@ID">Show This</span>
 }
```